# Issue with Bebas Neue font in Swift 3 app

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I am building an app in Swift 3 and I am facing an issue with the font. The font I am using is Bebas Neue. I select the label/text and change the font but font changes for just Regular only. Light and Thin ones do not work and font stays same. I am adding fonts using identity inspector.

It’s been a headache since yesterday. Please help.

Comment: Hi is your font stays same at execution time or on Storyboard itself ?

Comment: Font families and typefaces are two different things.

Comment: You are adding fonts programatically or from storyboard?
Verify that the Font's TargetMembership is Checked. ...